# Possible vulnerability by content disposition header

Tags: security, web, cors, csrf, content-disposition

Consider a response with Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 header and Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=text.txt header, with content-disp header appearing first , i am able to use the content-disp in my favor as a CSRF attack which make the file autodownload on the victim machine by including the URL as src in an iframe but if i am doing fetch i am blocked by CORB as the response does have application/json as content-type is there any way to smuggle the data i was able to download to a remote server

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to trick the victim's browser into making the request and perhaps even downloading the response somewhere, but you cannot access the response in Javascript unless it has an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that allows this.

The most you could do is measure the running time of the request and deduce something from that, using a mechanism like this:

```js
var running, time = 0;
function tick(ts) {
  if (running) time += ts;
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}
function attack() {
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  document.querySelector('form').submit();
}
```

```html
<body onload="attack()">
  <form action="https://cross.origin.resource" target="target"></form>
  <iframe name="target" onload="if (running) alert(time); else running = true;"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: What do u mean by downloading response elsewhere, it will downloaded only on the user machine right

Comment: is there any way to smuggle the downloaded data or create a stream and send to a remote server etc

Comment: Only to the user's machine.